# Filter out values using mstats

Tags: splunk

I am trying to filter out all negative values in my metrics, I would like to know if the filtering within the `mstats` call itself possible, to add something like `AND metrics_name:data.value > 0` to the query below?

```
| mstats avg(_value) WHERE metric_name="data.value" AND index="my_metrics" BY data.team
```

Currently, I am using the `msearch` and then filtering out the events, so my query is something like the one below but its too slow as I am pulling all the events:

```
| msearch index=my_metrics
| fields "metrics_name:data.value"
| where mvcount(mvfilter(tonumber(metrics_name:data.value') > 0)) >= 1 OR isnull('metrics_name:data.value')
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot filter or group-by the `_value` field with Metrics.

You may be able to speed up your search with `msearch` by including the metric_name in the filter.

```
| msearch index=my_metrics filter="metric_name=data.value"
```

Note that using `msearch` returns a sample of the metric values, not all of them, unless you specify `target_per_timeseries=0`

Refer to https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/Mstats